# How to increase arrow size and the text size

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .65 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
\tikzstyle reverse directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .65 with {\arrowreversed[arrowstyle]{stealth};}}}]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1][>=Stealth]

    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (0,0) -- (80,0);
    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (0,0) -- (0,87);    

    \draw[line width=0.5pt] plot [smooth] coordinates {
    (80,0) (83,20) (78,35) (82,50)  (77,65) (83,80) (63,90) (45,92) (35,88) (20,91) (0,87)
    };


    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (40,38) circle [radius=12.0];

    \draw[ultra thick,directed](-10,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw[ultra thick,directed](0,-10) -- (0,0);

    \node[] at (-10,-2) {$X$};
    \node[] at (2,-10) {$i\,Y$};
    \node[] at (1,1) {$z_{0}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Trying to increase the size of the text and arrow with thickness of the line with the arrow.
[image]Code:

Answer (score 1):

The default units are `x=1cm` and `y=1cm` so your drawing is HUGE!

If you change the `tikzpicture` line to this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm,y=2mm,yscale=-1][>=Stealth]
```

then the text and the arrows will look more reasonable.